# Sub Select to display on column or another

Tags: sql, subquery, multiple-columns

I have a database that contains a table with student information. (students).  Among other fields (LastName,FirstName and Gender etc.) it contains a field for High School GPA and another for College GPA.  I have been asked to only show one of these GPA fields in a report.  I'd like to create a sub query in a select statement to display only 1 GPA value.  Some students have both High school and College GPA's while others have only listed one.  For those that have listed both, I'd like the College GPA to be displayed.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to accomplish it.  Use a case statement.  This is only if you have a column for HighSchool and a column for College on the same row of data.

```
SELECT
x.Name
, x.GPA
, ISNULL(CollegeGPA, HighSchoolGPA) [GPA]
, CASE WHEN CollegeGPA IS NOT NULL
             THEN 'College'
             ELSE 'HighSchool'
             END [Type Of GPA]
FROM Data
```

If this won't work please post your database schema and some sample data.

Comment: I'm not sure that you fully understand my question.  I have 2 completely separate columns.  One called CollegeGPA and another called HSGPA. In my subselect I want to create a column for GPA that will either show the CollegeGPA or the HSGPA depending on what has been entered by the student.  I understand where you are going with the CASE statement, but I think there is more to it...

Comment: There's really not much too it.  Either the collegeGPA has data and you use it, or you use the hsGPA. The ISNULL statement is used if collegeGPA is null when no values are assigned. It all depends on how your data is structured. If collegeGPA is 0 then you will need to modify the CASE statment to look for > 0. Get it?